# Static IP with Different Internet Service Provider for server

Tags: networking, static, ip

I have one setup where my server is already having Static IP address from one of my Internet Service Provider ISP (X). Now ISP (X) service are not good its went for maintenance mode quite frequently hence I decided to keep one more ISP(Y) provider as backup of it. Condition here is i dont want to change my static IP address but i want to keep both ISP providers running on if any one of them fail other can serve requests.

I have single server with Two NIC cards and Windows Server 2008 R2 configuration.

Many Thanks for your valuable suggestion and feedback.

Comment: PS: after I answered I realised that this question is off-topic for StackOverflow. SuperUser would be more appropriate IMHO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IP address you get from your provider will only work through *that* provider. You can only use IP addresses across multiple providers if you have **PI** (provider independent) IP addresses and your providers agree to route those PI addresses for you. This will require more expensive internet connections though, and you'll need someone who knows the BGP protocol that is used for this kind of routing. A problem can be that in several regions of the world ([APNIC](http://www.apnic.net/) and [RIPE](http://www.ripe.net/) at the time of writing) the IPv4 address pools are empty and it is no longer possible there to get PI IPv4 addresses at all.

Another way of using fixed IP addresses across multiple physical connections is by using an overlay ISP which provides services based on [LISP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Locator/Identifier_Separation_Protocol). Such a provider will give you the same IP addresses independent from the provider(s) that you use to physically connect to the internet. For example: you have a DSL connection from ISP A and a cable connection from ISP B. Both those ISPs will give you at least one IP address. LISP only uses those addresses to communicate with the LISP ISP, who will give you the IP address(es) that you will use on your server. If ISP A breaks down you can still use ISP B to communicate with the LISP ISP, and if ISP B breaks down as well (or becomes too expensive, or ...) then you can just get a new connection from ISP C and use them to connect to the LISP ISP. As long as you have *some* connectivity to the internet you can use the LISP addresses.

LISP based ISPs are often offering such service under names like "Cloud Based Routing" or something similar.

Comment: Thanks Sander for your time and valuable input.